# Static Method for handling null returns

Tags: c#

So I have created a provider (a few of them actually) and I am realising there is a bit of a pattern in some of my logic. It is being repeated and I reckon I can remove lots of lines of code if I can just create this extension method :D

So, basically what is happening is something like this:

```
// Get our item to be deleted
var model = await this._service.GetAsync(id);

// If we have nothing, throw an error
if (model == null)
    throw new HttpException(404, string.Format(Resources.GenericNotFound, "List item"));
```

Now, I do this in a lot of places, not just for deleting, but for updating.
I would like to create an extension method that allows me to do something like this:

```
// Get our item to be deleted
var model = await this._service.GetAsync(id).ThowIfNull("List item");
```

I also need this to work with any return type. So in this case it might be an **Account**, but there will be a provider that also has this code returning an **Order** but I need the extension method to work for both.

I think the challenge here is the async bit, but I might be wrong!

Anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: Well one possibility is `(await this._wervice.GetAsync(id)).ThrowIfNull("List item");` if you want the extension method on whatever `model` is (or maybe even on `object`) instead of the `Task<T>`

Comment: Could you write this up as an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility to avoid the async-await part is to make the extension method work on the type returned inside of the `Task`

```
public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T obj, string message) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format(Resources.GenericNotFound, message));
    return obj;
}
```

I made the extension method generic as I don't know what type `model` is.  Then you can just use it like this.

```
var model = (await this._service.GetAsync(id)).ThrowIfNull("List item");
```

By putting the `await` in parenthesis you make sure it will wait on the task and unwrap it before passing the result to the extension method.

The other option would be to make the extention method work on `Task<T>`

```
public static async Task<T> ThrowIfNullAsync<T>(this Task<T> task, string message) 
where T : class
{
    var obj = await task;
    if (obj == null)
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format(Resources.GenericNotFound, message));
    return obj;
}
```

And you wouldn't need the parenthesis.

```
var model = await this._service.GetAsync(id).ThrowIfNullAsync("List item");
```

But this means that the exception is now wrapped in the task which may or may not be desirable depending on how you use this method.

Comment: You don't need to make them have diffrent names, just have them use the same name and be overloads of each other, this is the same way `Task.Run` works. That way you can use `ThrowIfNull` on both synchronous and asynchronous methods.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain True, but I personally subscribe to the philosophy of naming async methods differently.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an extension method on any `T`:

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(this T obj, string message)
    {
        if (obj == null) 
            throw new HttpException(404,
               string.Format(Resources.GenericNotFound, message));
        return obj;
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the return type you can use `object`, but that will incur boxing for value types (not sure I'd use this actually):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static void ThrowIfNull(this object obj, string message)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
    }
}
```

And then use it on any return type:

```
async Task SomeAsyncMethod()
{
    (await Foo()).ThrowIfNull("hello");
}

public Task<int> Foo()
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Throws a 404 Not found exception
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The model to check</param>
/// <param name="name">The name to display in the message</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T ThrowIfNotFound<T>(this T model, string name)
{

    // If we have nothing, throw an error
    if (model == null)
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format(Resources.GenericNotFound, name));

    // Return our model
    return model;
}
```